# Drupal 8 search api solr want to get all items

Tags: search, solr, module, drupal-8

i´m using drupal8 with solr 7.4 and the search api module. I don´t find a way to configure the search api to get all indexed items by searching with ""(nothing an put enter) or searching by "*". How can i enable such a search behavior?

Thanks a lot
Tim

Answer (score 0):

As upto my understanding on your question, You can Create Facets and configure the filters by specific taxonomy terms or content types. Before that check the fields what you are indexing into the solr.

Comment: I don`t want to search for a specific items, i only want to get all items of the index, by searching for "*" or something else. In my oppinion the faces are  only working if i have some results.